# windows file sharing - one computer cannot view others shares

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing

advanced file and printer sharing A can do it on B but B can't on A, it prompts for user/pass

I have 2 computers. Both Win XP Pro

Both advanced file sharing.. I want that.

But when I connect comp A to Comp B, (start..run..\B) I get a user/pass prompt.
B can view folders on A though start..run..\A.

The problem is A to B.

If it helps.. 
I created duplicate user accounts on each computer. But I not logged in as the same one.
eg.
on comp A i'm logged in as nameQ, on comp B logged in as nameR
compA has an account nameR, and compB has account nameQ

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13072/oldp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution was one of the netsh commands.

netsh winsock reset catalog

netsh int reset all

netsh ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

some other symptoms of the problem I was able to find.. that may help diagnose the same problem
Besides, when trying to do \compblah
"\compblah is not accessible. 
You might not have permission to ue this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowd. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again""

net view \computername
net use Z: \computername\sharename

net view.  Gave.error 5 (apparently there are various error 5 messages one can get. I know I got error 5 though)
net use   Gave error 53
I didn't jot the text of them down at the time and it's fine now so I can't see what they were. But now
net view \computername
net use \computername
both don't give errors.
The netsh commands(one some or all of them) fixed it.

a good site is michna's http://winhlp.com/wxnet.htm
though I do suggest still if solving it from that, putting the ans here too so it's not just on one site!

Another symptom of the problem, which is now cleared up, is sysinternals psloggedon, gave an error..  "Error opening HKEY_USERS for \compblah ...Unable to query resource logons  "

that is now fine.

apparently many "assymetrical problems" can be FW or 3rd party FW or remnants of, but not in this case since I don't have 3rd party FW. Win FW with exceptions put in,was fine.

net use * /D  (clearing the cache helped in my testing) appaerntly it can get rid of shares.. but my shared folders seem fine after it.  IT was a useful command 'cos it meant that if I logged on successfully as say Guest(not really what I want), then it wouldn't keep going in automatically as it, it would prompt again. so that just helped a bit in testing things.

there is
LSP Fix and WinsockXPFix from
http://www.cexx.org/lspfix.htm
(can also check softpedia and/or majorgeeks for them) though if they touch the registry and are for xp it maybe isn't a good idea to try them in later windows versions..

though I didn't try them..

as mentioned, solution was
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int reset
netsh ip reset resetlog.txt

and if any of those, it was probably the first one of those 3 commands that solved it.

**Added**

The famous "hanselman" has (or had) a blog post called

> The Nuclear Option: Resetting The Crap Out Of Your Network Adapters

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20150329031816/http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx

, 
which has some commands that helped.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
netsh int reset all
netsh int ip reset
netsh int ipv4 reset
netsh int ipv6 reset
netsh winsock reset
```

and try the commands I mentioned earlier too (I think they worked well for XP, no harm in trying them in later windows versions)

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int reset all
netsh ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

Also, bleepingcomputer has a windows all in one repair, and there's two tools called "far bar" by/(or at least from the site) bleeping computer that may help

Comment: this was an absolutely brilliant solution! those 3 netsh commands are very important!

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx

Comment: also bleepingcomputer has a windows all in one repair, and there's two tools called "far bar" by/(or at least from the site) bleeping computer that may help

Answer (score 0):

When it prompts for user name/pass does it not accept them?  Make sure the password is what you think it is.  It's possible you mistyped on one computer when you set up the account.  If you want it to not ask for your user/pass when you connect, you need to either log on to the local computer as a user (with identical name and pass) to an account that exists on the remote computer, or, once you've established a connection, use the

```
net use \\server\share /persistent:yes /savecred
```

command to have it remember.

Comment: "When it prompts for user name/pass does it not accept them?"
correct, it doesn't. It doesn't keep prompting though, I find it gives this error message
"\\compblah is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions."