# How do I find and replace 'whole words only', in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I want to be able to find and replace `eat` with `Eat` in Microsoft Word 2007. However, I don’t want to replace *every* occurrence of `eat` such as those that can be found inside other words such as `great` and `meat`.

I have tried doing this using the regular *Find and Replace* tool, but I get words with capital letters in the middle.

Is there a way I can just replace `eat` with `Eat` if it only exists on its own?

Comment: Didn't you tell it to search for a match on whole words only?

Comment: Ah excellent! Didn't see that. Thank you I will try it.

Comment: well, besides the suggestion.. a less good way might be replace <space>eat<space> for others like beginning of a line you might need a regex.. So, the "whole words only" that randolph suggests is probably the best way.

Comment: -1 and do you really want to find and replace ms word 2007? really? do you want to replace word 2007 with 2013? no I don't think you d. you should title your question better. (Though if you did it'd probably lose more value for you 'cos it'd make the answer so blatantly easy to google for wouldn't it)

Comment: @barlop, that’s good, but `␣eat␣` won’t catch `He really liked to eat.` Also, this site is like a wiki, you are free to improve it by editing it yourself. In fact, while it is more polite give a more experienced user a nudge to fix/improve their post themselves, for novice users who might not yet know better, it is perfectly fine, even advisable, for experienced users like yourself to take the initiative and do it for them.

Comment: `Didn't you tell it to search for a match on whole words only?`   @RandolphWest, apparently not because it seems that that option is hidden away with other, more advanced and less commonly used options. That’s actually pretty poor design because while most of those are uncommon options which *should* be tucked away behind a `[More>>]` button, *Match Case* and *Match Whole Word* are very common options that users are likely familiar with. Shame Microsoft. ¬_¬

Comment: @Synetech many novice users of superuser are very capable of writing a useful title when they write a question, no nudge even required. if they're not capable, it's not because they are a "novice". Looking back at the first question I asked here http://superuser.com/questions/163150/windows-file-sharing-one-computer-cannot-view-others-shares   it was well titled, got a favorite and 1K views. Your first question got 4 votes a favorite and 2K views.  As for this question, the question is so easily googlable, a good title won't add much value. It's worthless IMO.

Comment: @Synetech for you, and for a joke, I made the title very good. Though I think it makes it even more blatantly obvious how useless the question is.

Comment: @barlop, don’t forget that the Internet is global and this site is open to foreigners. Plus, the option is hidden, so it makes sense that they may be confused. Actually, the new title makes it a *better* question.

Comment: @Synetech  my new title was taking the piss really.. i'm glad you like it, I thought you would! Also, it's not a help site. So if you think the question now is an improvement.. the fact is it's so easily googlable.. It's not useful to have the junk in the database.

Comment: @barlop, I know you meant it as a joke, but it really does make it better because as I said to Randolph, the whole-words option is a common option for search and that they chose to hide it away is bizarre. You and I may have instinctively clicked `[More >>]` to find it, but many users would never think to look there for that option even if they were aware of it in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11732/discussion-between-barlop-and-synetech)

Comment: @barlop your suggestion for using a space before and after is a rubbish worthless suggestion. Why suggest when Randolph West had already kindly pointed out the correct way! Shows that you are novice and use novice ways!

Comment: @barlop your rant about having a good title is devoid of reality! If I had known that something called whole words exists then I wouldn't have asked this question! With your edited title the question looks silly because the answer is in the question.

Comment: @user277816 Perhaps you didn't read the comment, firstly I outlined how to do it, by saying use regexes(this can do a lot more thna just the simple example of " eat ", but I didn't elaborate because I said to use randolph's way).  I actually wrote there that randolph's suggestion is the thing to use. I didn't write what had already been written. It is good to have alternative solutions. I am well aware of searching for "whole words" - almost anybody would be. But i'm not going to repeat a solution somebody else has mentioned.

Comment: I agree regarding the title, check my edit, but synetech is very experienced and he prefers the title I gave it, so I amused myself.  The question looked silly before, and it still looks silly now. Try to  suggest a good title where if you google it, you don't immediately find the answer on loads of links.  "devoid of reality" is good English, there goes anybodys' theory that your english is poor to explain your bad title(like you want to change ms office) and your inability to (find the words to?) google your problem and see the massive number of links with the simple answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **Find and Replace** window in the *Replace* tab, click the **More >>** button to display more Search Options. After where it says *Search:* click the dropdown arrow and select *All*. Put a check mark to the left of where it says: *Match case*. Put another check mark to the left of where it says: *Find whole words only*.

In the *Find what* input box type `eat`.
In the *Replace with* input box type `Eat`.

Click the **Replace All** button to replace all occurrences of "eat" with "Eat".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles searching for the word "he" because I got all the "the" words.  For some reason What worked in the end was clicking "match prefix" and "match suffix".  "Find whole words only" didn't work for me. I didn't need to use the replace function.

Comment: Does this address the question of *whole words only*?