# Ethernet port doesn't work while Wi-Fi does

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet

So I'm trying to fix this problem for a while now and have seen many similar problems, but all of them got solved through one of the steps listed below - not mine. The problem is:

Ethernet cable connected from home router to the port results in no network connection. It shows:

- first 15-20 seconds all the icons are fine, the network center shows "connected". Can't ping any website despite that though.
- right after I get the exclamation mark with yellow triangle icon as the connection icon. And it stays like that.

My gear is Samsung RF-511 S04 with Windows 7 x64 Home Premium SP1.

What I've checked:

- first I disconnected wireless card, Ethernet is still on of course.
- different cable doesn't work
- different router port doesn't work
- other ubuntu laptop **works**
- finally - switching to ubuntu on my "broken" laptop **works**

So I know the network card is fine. What I did next:

- I see the default gate for ethernet is fine.
- I updated (didn't help), uninstalled and installed back again the drivers, didn't help either.
- The Windows diagnostic tool reports no problems found.

Any clue what could I check next? I would appreciate any hint on that.
 

edit

**@user604857 Kevin**
The ipconfig /all for the ethernet connection below:

Ethernet adapter local area connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix : home
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . . : E8-11-32-99-FA-BB
   DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease obtained. . . . . . . . : 11 June 2016 19:52:03
   Lease Expires. . . . . . . . . : 12 June 2016 19:52:03
   Default gateway. . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                                       192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . : Enabled

Looks like I have IPv6 physical address, though I have IPv6 disabled in the properties and IPv4 set to automatic - see screenshot - not in English, sorry, but it should be recognisable.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how on earth have you not attempted reinstalling drivers for your network card

Comment: "I updated (didn't help), uninstalled and installed back again the drivers, didn't help either." <- I guess that's what you mean I had to do?

Comment: ok this probably won't help but what about right click  hten click diagnose http://www.ptd.net/sites/default/files/Troubleshooting_Cable_Windows_7_Diagnose_Step5.jpg  (win7 has that option and you're on win7)

Comment: just foudn these two programs, can't vouch for tem but may help. they're reputable sites.   majorgeeks i'd be surprised if any of their stuff had malware and bleepingcomputer is an anti malware site so definitely no malware there http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/complete_internet_repair.html   and http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/netadapter-repair-all-in-one/   and a thing you can download here https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/936211   a microsoft fix it thing. All long shots.

Comment: there's also reinstalling the tcp ip stack

Comment: Diagnosing was one of the first things I tried, but it shows no problems detected. The programs you suggest do basically same things as commands by @DavidPostill in another answer, well, they also didn't help as I commented there. The Microsoft Fix It thing relates to Firewall problems only, I didn't have nothing to lose, so tried it also. No result.

Comment: how about trying it with a fresh windows installation? you could try it with a winpe first  britec has a good tutorial on making a winpe http://youtube.com/watch?v=E0eslpRmznE

Comment: I don't really consider wiping Windows, WinPE would be an interesting proposition, but since Ethernet port worked with Ubuntu installed on the same computer and Ubuntu Live, I don't think it will give me any more info on the problem? Or am I wrong?

Comment: A fresh windows doesn't necessarily mean wiping it, you could make a new partition and put windows on it or try it on another hard drive lying around.  Anyhow, if it works under WinPE(not such hassle as run off a CD/USB) it increases the chances greatly, that it will work under a fresh windows, and if it works under a fresh windows, then you know that recreating your windows installation would be an option for a fix that would work.  And if for some bizarre reason a fresh win installation  doesn't work then you know that wiping ur existing windows installation to try to make it work is futile

Comment: if I won't solve the problem less invasively, I will finally have to. I'm sure it would work since it works on same-machine Ubuntu, but we know reinstalling Win is quite a pain when you have to do it on your personal laptop ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Any clue what could I check next?

Reinitialise the network states by running the following commands in a `cmd` shell:

1. Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh winsock reset catalog
   ```
2. Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh int ip reset reset.log
   ```
3. Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall reset
   ```
4. Flush DNS resolver cache :

   ```
   ipconfig /flushdns
   ```
5. Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

   ```
   ipconfig /registerdns
   ```
6. Flush routing table:

   ```
   route /f
   ```

   This last command requires a restart.

Note:

- See the last two further reading links for further things to try.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.
- [The Nuclear Option: Resetting The Crap Out Of Your Network Adapters in Vista](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx)
- [windows file sharing - one computer cannot view others shares](https://superuser.com/questions/163150/windows-file-sharing-one-computer-cannot-view-others-shares)

Comment: Thank you. I did above, with rebooting, but it didn't change the situation.

Comment: For the record http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx   and a related superuser link with a bunch of these commands  http://superuser.com/questions/163150/windows-file-sharing-one-computer-cannot-view-others-shares

Comment: @barlop Thanks for the comment. I will add to the answer for completeness.

Comment: Resetting the crap out of my network adapter didn't help, I'll research other links you posted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its worth eliminating the DHCP element so set a new manual ip address with same gateway and try again.
Also when you try with Ubuntu record the ip address used and other details.

By the way, the Physical Address displayed is nothing to do with IPV6. It is the Hardware or Mac Address of your Ethernet port. Every network device has a Mac address encoded when the device is made in the factory

In addition you should connect to the management page of the router and check its network setup ip nets or sub nets and verify the settings relating to the ethernet port. Presumably you should be able to do this with ubuntu. Then set up logging on the device, retry your ethernet connection, back to ubuntu to check the log!

If you still dont want to go down the wipe route, we need to test the known facts more rigorously. can you supply the ip addresses masks and gateways on each device in your testing especially when you tried static addresses and confirm that you are not using a crossover cable inadvertently (the same cable should be used in all tests). In fact the simplest test would be with a crossover cable or alternatively a switch with only your good ubuntu laptop and the bad one connected
then set up both ethernet ports:-

with:

good ubuntu:-
static address
10.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.2

windows:-
static address
10.0.0.2 mask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1

and try to ping 
if it works the port hardware should be ok.

Comment: With other pc I checked how the router behaves when I connect to it - everything seems to be correct, compared to another ethernet connection, at least there are no limitations. Can't get the system logs of the router because it's provided by an ISP (not a super-configurable gear). Though I tried assigning static IP address - no result.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to remember that Windows does not usually handle both wifi and ethernet port being enabled at the same time - unless the machine is a server.
So I would go into the network tool and disable wifi and then enable the ethernet driver, and test the ethernet port.
In the microsoft world only servers are allowed to be 'multi homed' - that is, operate 2 network ports simultaneously. It ensures that people have to buy the Server Operating Systems!
hope this helps

Comment: It appears that my non-Server Windows 8 machine is able to use both Ethernet and Wi-Fi at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I wrote in the description that I turned off the wireless card as a first step.

Comment: And Ben N seems to be right, I remember I didn't have any issue with the ethernet-wifi mix in Win XP x32 and Win7 x64. Just plugged in a cable and disabled wi-fi (what even wasn't always neccessary - it turned off by itself)

Comment: -1  if what you were saying were true then a)have a proper source (it'd be a well known problem if it were true) and b)He is not describing some issue of ethernet card xor wireless. He's saying his ethernet socket is not working on windows at all, whether wireless is on or off. So what you're saying which is probably false anyway, is irrelevant.

Comment: @BenN yeah this answer can't be right and is completely unsourced and isn't even addressing the problem the OP is having